using Powershell authorize WMI access from Computer A to Computer B
I have 2 computers A & B and I am Local Admin on both computers.
I am using an application named VisualCron to remote execute a batch file from computer A (VisualCron) to computer B (Batch file)
The execution failed with error code:
"Exception in Task: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
I use the following Powershell command from Computer A to test VMI access from Computer A to Computer B, because, it is easier for me to run 1 Powershell cammnd rather than running VisualCron.
$colSettings = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "Computer B"
The error is:
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
Please, note this is NOT a Powershell error but a DCOM or WMI settings error.
Therefore, I need to know how to authorize WMI access on Computer B when Computer A execute the below Powershell script
$colSettings = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "Computer B"
Any help, is more than "Welcome"
Thanks.

If you use get-ciminstance you just need to enable remote powershell.

On the Target Computer, Remote Powershell has been enable. The problem remains.

Something like get-ciminstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "Computer B" works for me.
